# Checking 1000 urls if they exist or not, is there a quick way for this?

Tags: php

I have an array of urls (~1000 urls in it), i want to check all of them if they exist or not. Here is my current code:

```
$south_east_png_endings = array();
for($x=1;$x<=25;$x++) {
    for($y=1;$y<=48;$y++) {
        $south_east_png_endings[] ="${x}s${y}e.png";
    }
}

foreach ($south_east_png_endings as $se){
    $url = 'http://imgs.xkcd.com/clickdrag/'.$se;
    $file_headers = @get_headers($url);
    if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
        // echo 'Does not exist';
    }
    else
    {
        echo $url;
    }
}
```

This script works, it echos out all the working urls, but the process is too long (takes several minutes to complete). Is there a way to do this faster or is this as fast as it gets? Maybe i can use curl_timeout functions to shorten the time?

Comment: I recommend to fork processes: http://chemicaloliver.net/programming/speeding-up-php-using-process-forking-for-image-resizing/

Answer (score 3):

1) get_headers() actually uses GET requests, which are not needed if you just want to know if a file exists. Use HEAD instead, [example from the manual](http://php.net/get_headers):

```
<?php
// By default get_headers uses a GET request to fetch the headers. If you
// want to send a HEAD request instead, you can do so using a stream context:
stream_context_set_default(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'HEAD'
        )
    )
);
$headers = get_headers('http://example.com');
?>
```

2) since those checks can be easily run in parallel, you should use separate threads/processes to do the checking. However, if you're doing this from home, your router might choke on 1000 requests at once, so you might want to use something like 5-20 concurrent threads.

Answer (score 0):

For paralleling check you may use [multi_curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php). It might be pretty fast. Here some [example](http://www.somacon.com/p537.php). Cause it's more complex than example by @eis.

P.S. Also with curl you can use trick with method HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

```
function _isUrlexist($url) {
    $flag = false;
    if ($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => true
            ));
        curl_exec($ch);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);

        $flag = ($info == 200) ? true : false;
    }
    return $flag;
}
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.  In particular, does it follow 301 and/or 302 redirects, or simply report failure for those?